# React setstate does not work in IE11 after render is called

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11, render, setstate

I am new to react development and I have a react app where on the componentDidMount am setting the state of value as "add" and it renders the div content for "add" and once button click on the add div am calling an addstate method
where am setting the state of the value as "edit" and it renders the div content with respect to "edit" and where i call again the addstate method through done method call.

In this case the fetch call from addstate method is happening to the backend but the state is  not setting back to edit..it fails only in IE11. It works on chrome, firefox and mobile devices.
If i remove the piece of code "Value:edit" in addstate method its working good. But my requirement needs to render based upon different scenarios. so basically am able to set the state of the result only once in IE11. it does not work repeatedly.

````
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: "test",
            items: []
        }

    };

    addState() {
        fetch("/local/addThings").then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        value: "edit",
                        items: result
                    });
                   }
            )
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }

     done() {
          this.setState({
               value: "add"                     
              });

             }
    componentDidMount() {

        fetch("/local/getThings")
            .then(
                (result) => {
                       this.setState({
                            value: "add"
                        });

                }
            )
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error)); 

    }

    render() {
        const { value, items } = this.state;

        if (value === "add") {
            return <div >
                <div >
                    <ul >
                        <li onClick={() => this.addState()}>
                            <div>
                                <img src="Add.png" />
                                <center><p>AddButton</p></center>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                ;
        }
        if (value === "edit") {
            return (<div>
                <div >
                    <ul >
                        <li onClick={() => this.done()}>
                            <div >
                                <img src="Save.png" />
                                <center><p>SaveButton</p></center>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                         {items.map(item => (
                                      <center><p>{item.name}</p></center>

                                </li> 
                            ))}
                   </ul>

                </div>
            </div>

            );
        }

        }

}
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById("details")); ```
````

Comment: Are you polyfilling ```fetch``` functionality with something like [whatwg-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch)?  The Fetch API is not supported natively in IE11.

Comment: Yes am using polyfill and fetch using  whatwg-fetch to make fetch work in IE11. Fetch is working fine for me..the issue is with the setstate of the value on the second time

Comment: And is your transpiler converting the arrow functions to normal ```function``` declarations?

Comment: Yes, function declarations are getting converted fine . I have the problem of the setstate only in IE11..My code works fine with chrome.

Comment: Right, meaning the issue almost certainly lies with one of the many commonly used ES6+ features that modern browsers support but IE does not.  Are you receiving any errors? I'd try running ```console.log(this)``` inside your fetch callback to see if it exists and is referring to the component properly. Same thing with the fetch result.

Comment: Also, what is the data structure of your ```result```?  Typically, API responses are objects, but you are treating it as an array in your render method

Comment: Console.log(this) inside callback prints the first time. It neither prints anything nor throws error the second time.

Comment: IE doesn't support `json()` natively: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json#Browser_compatibility. That might be the issue it doesn't work in IE. Please try to import polyfills to make it supported in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding your method and refer to it directly in your `onClick` event:

```
lass App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: "test",
            items: []
        }
        this.addState = this.addState.bind(this);

    };

    addState() {
        fetch("/local/addThings").then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        value: "edit",
                        items: result
                    });
                   }
            )
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }

     done() {
          this.setState({
               value: "add"                     
              });

             }
    componentDidMount() {

        fetch("/local/getThings")
            .then(
                (result) => {
                       this.setState({
                            value: "add"
                        });

                }
            )
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error)); 

    }

    render() {
        const { value, items } = this.state;

        if (value === "add") {
            return <div >
                <div >
                    <ul >
                        <li onClick={this.addState}>
                            <div>
                                <img src="Add.png" />
                                <center><p>AddButton</p></center>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
                ;
        }
        if (value === "edit") {
            return (<div>
                <div >
                    <ul >
                        <li onClick={() => this.done()}>
                            <div >
                                <img src="Save.png" />
                                <center><p>SaveButton</p></center>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                         {items.map(item => (
                                      <center><p>{item.name}</p></center>

                                </li> 
                            ))}
                   </ul>

                </div>
            </div>

            );
        }

        }

}
```

Comment: I tried binding too. It did not make it work...Still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I added settimeout in my methods and it worked in IE. It seems like the response was slower in IE for the API calls. Not sure if there is a workaround or this is the right approach.

````
        fetch("/local/addThings").then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                 setTimeout(() => {
                    this.setState({
                        value: "edit",
                        items: result
                    });
                     }, 200);
                       }
            )
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }```
````